# VBA cutting a Web/Location Address

Tags: vba, excel

I am having abit of trouble with some VBA code for cutting a file location.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub TESTING()

 Dim strLocation as string
 Dim strFile as string

 strLocation = "TEST\test\TEST\test_file_name.csv"

 strFile = Right$(strLocation, InStr(strLocation, "\") - 1)
 MsgBox strFile

End Sub
```

I wish to implement code so that "test_file_name.csv" is returned as my strFile. The file names will vary hence I am attemping to cut from the right to the first backslash.

Comment: InStr() returns the first position which wont help you here, instead use InStrRev() which returns the last position, then mid() to read from that point

Comment: @AlexK. Thankyou! This only returns "t_file_name.csv" and not the entire file name.

Comment: Or, you can test if the file exists at the same time with `strFile = Dir(strLocation)`

Comment: `file = mid$(strLocation, InStrRev(strLocation, "\") + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some ways

1)

```
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strFile As String

strLocation = "TEST\test\TEST\test_file_name.csv"    
strFile = Right$(strLocation, Len(strLocation) - InStrRev(strLocation, "\"))
```

2)

```
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strFile As String  

strLocation = "TEST\test\TEST\test_file_name.csv"
strFile = Split(strLocation, "\")(UBound(Split(strLocation, "\")))
```

3)

```
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strFile As String

strLocation = "TEST\test\TEST\test_file_name.csv"
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strFile = .GetFileName(strLocation)
End With
```

Comment: Option 1) cuts the name short but options 2) & 3) work perfectly! Thankyou!!

Comment: You are welcome. But can't understand the issue with option 1